# Use SharePoint REST to show contents SkyDrive Pro with Remote Site

Tags: rest, sharepoint, oauth, public

I have managed to get an access token from a non .NET environment from SharePoint public. I am now trying to use it for REST calls to list folders/files on SkyDrive Pro. I have followed this approach: http://jomit.blogspot.nl/2013/03/authentication-and-authorization-with.html

The url for a rest call looks like this:
targetUrl + "_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/')";
I also pass the access token in the request header authorization.

however, sharepoint responds with FileNotFound in the response body. Also when I UrlEncode it to prevend any errors caused by the space in the folder name. I have 3 files in that folder.

As a scope in the OAuth process I have given the value "AllSites.Read".
I have a feeling that the url is not proparly constructed, but I don't know whats wrong with it.

tx in advance